# Is it possible to use widetext environment in latex article document when using Texlive

Tags: two-column

Am writing an article with two columns. I want to include a long equation to appear as shown in the picture attached. Am using windows(Texlive) and it is giving the !Latex error: "widetext.sty " not found. How can I achieve that? Is it possible to include the widetext.sty file or it possible to define a new environment equivalent to that.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: And where does `widetext.sty` come from? It is not known to CTAN.

Comment: @Noah Have you tried omniscient Google? Just typing in `widetext.sty`, gives me [https://blog.pnas.org/widetext.sty](https://blog.pnas.org/widetext.sty). Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks, Gernot. but have one more challenge ' where do I copy it to please?'